# draw neural network diagram in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, neural-network

Is it possible to draw a neural network diagram in `ggplot`.

A simple ggplot code to which can create the shallow neural network diagram with one hidden layer network in ggplot (number of neurons can be given as input)

A desired diagram is attached below. Currently I use power point/paint to create the neural network diagrams.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(nnet)
    library(caret)
    
    # data
    x <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    y <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
    choice <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
    tbl <- tibble(x, y, choice)
    tbl$choice = as.factor(tbl$choice)
    
    myControl <- trainControl(## n-fold CV
      method = "repeatedcv",
      number = 2,
      repeats = 5,
      verboseIter = TRUE)
    
    nnGrid <-  expand.grid(size = 2,
                           decay = seq(0, 0.1, 0.3))
    
    nnetFit <- train(choice ~ .,
                     data = tbl,
                     method = "nnet",
                     tuneGrid = nnGrid,
                     trace = FALSE,
                     maxit = 6000,
                     trControl = myControl)
```

[image]

Comment: I would use igraph for this. A fabulous tutorial can be found here https://kateto.net/networks-r-igraph

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge. I make use of the ggnet2 function.

Have a look at the documentation: https://briatte.github.io/ggnet/